# How would i create a delivery date notifier

Tags: c#, sql-server, datagridview

I would like to notify 30 days before the exact date of delivery, but I don't know how to. I am using `datagridview` to display the data from the database.

I would like to create a countdown which will notify me each day until the exact date for the delivery.

```
DateTime answer = today.AddDays(30);`enter code here`
string convert1 = today.ToString("MM/dd/yy"); //Today's date
string convert = answer.ToString("MM/dd/yy"); //Today + 30days

sqlcon.Open();
command.Connection = sqlcon;

command.CommandText = "SELECT [ID], [Delivery Date], [Delivery Time], [Delivery Description] From Delivery WHERE [Delivery Date] < '" + convert + "' ORDER BY [Delivery Date] ASC";
using (SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
{
    while (reader.Read())
    {
        if (today.Date < answer.Date)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Upcoming Delivery in less than 30 days!" + "\n\n*Delivery Date:\n" + "     " + reader["Delivery Date"].ToString() + "\n\n*Delivery Description:\n" + "     " + reader["Delivery Description"].ToString());
         }
     }
 }
 sqlcon.Close();
```

Answer (score 2):

You can create windows service which will regularly check for entities to notify. Topshelf (https://github.com/Topshelf/Topshelf) is a right way to go with windows services.